# Merging GitLab repositories in another (existing) GitLab installation

Tags: gitlab

My company has merged with another company and we both use GitLab. We're in the process of moving our GitLab installations into one installation, but I'm not quite sure if this can be done (with keeping merge request, wiki, etc... data from both installations).

The repositories themselves are uniquely named, but the migrate paths I find on [Google](https://www.google.be/search?q=gitlab%20migrate) only use complete backup/restore methods.

Is there a way to export/import one repository from/to GitLab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a GitLab issue describing this: [Add Project Import/Export Functionality](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/3050).